# Odoo 10 behind Nginx reverse proxy not recognizing real client IP address

Tags: nginx, odoo, reverse-proxy, werkzeug

I installed Odoo, it's fully working. Except werkzeug shows 127.0.0.1 as a client IP, even with that config : `proxy_mode = True` in `odoo.conf` and also tried to start Odoo manually with --proxy-mode .

Nginx config containing :

```
proxy_read_timeout 720s;
proxy_connect_timeout 720s;
proxy_send_timeout 720s;

proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_redirect off;
```

I even tried upgrading werkzeug to latest version with PIP.

Odoo still logs `werkzeug: 127.0.0.1`

I would like to get the real client IP in order to use the Link Tracker.

The operating system is CentOS 7, I installed Odoo with the RPM package `yum localinstall`.

Is someone know how that I can fix that ?